# Why My Web Page is Suddenly Refreshed

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo GridView. After calling onSearch function the web page is suddenly refreshed. How can I solve this issue?

This is my Grid:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
        selectable: "row",
        scrollable: false,
        autoBind: false,
        columns: [
                { title: "Status", width: '200px', template: '#if(Allowed){#Yes#}else{#No#}#' },
                { title: "Description", field: "Message" }
        ],
        dataSource: vm.entity.MyDataSource
    });
```

And this is my code:

```
entity: {
            MyDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                transport: {
                    read: {
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'url goes here...',
                        data: {
                            code: function () { return '123' }
                        }
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    data: "Data",
                    parse: function (data) {
                        return data;
                    }
                }
            }),

            onSearch: function () {
                vm.entity.MyDataSource.read();
            }
        }
```

Everything is OK and result is correctly returned and GridView is filled with data but after 1 second the web page is suddenly refreshed.

Comment: Are you able to isolate this into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like when you call onSearch() function you also navigate to url. Check if search function is not called by:

link with href and onclick function:

```
<a href="" onclick="search()" />
```

button inside of form:

```
<form>
    <button onclick="search">Search</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. My button type was set to 'submit'. I changed it to 'button' and everything's working well now.